# rvm pkg install ree_dependencies gives error about autoreconf

Tags: ruby, rvm, linux-mint

I am running this command on Linux Mint 14 Mate:

```
rvm pkg install ree_dependencies --verify-downloads 1
```

and I get this error:

```
Fetching ncurses-5.7.tar.gz to /home/john/.rvm/archives
Extracting ncurses to /home/john/.rvm/src/ncurses-5.7
Prepare ncurses in /home/john/.rvm/src/ncurses-5.7.
Error running 'autoreconf -is --force', please read /home/john/.rvm/log/ncurses/autoreconf.log
Configuring ncurses in /home/john/.rvm/src/ncurses-5.7.
Error running './configure --prefix=/home/john/.rvm/usr --with-shared --disable-rpath --without-debug --without-ada --enable-safe-sprintf --enable-sigwinch --without-progs', please read /home/john/.rvm/log/ncurses/configure.log
Compiling ncurses in /home/john/.rvm/src/ncurses-5.7.
Error running 'make', please read /home/john/.rvm/log/ncurses/make.log
```

and here is the log file:

```
configure:5967: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DIVERT_HELP
    If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
    See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

I googled for the solution, but got nothing.
Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `ree_dependencies` you should read output of `rvm requirements` - it will show you what needs to be installed.

A word of advice - REE is based on Ruby 1.8 which is no longer maintained, only security fixes will be released for few months, you really should try a newer ruby like 1.9.3, or if it's new project - try ruby 2.0.0 preview2:

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0
```